# Autoformat currency if user type numeric in textbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I have a textbox that can only be entered character digits. I use the TextChanged . I want when the user enters the number it will bring up a textbox automatically format numbers with currency .

i use this code for TextChanged:

```
 private void validateTextDouble(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception X = new Exception();

        TextBox T = (TextBox)sender;

        try
        {
            if (T.Text != "-")
            {
                double x = double.Parse(T.Text);
                textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)).ToString();


                if (T.Text.Contains(','))
                    throw X;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                int CursorIndex = T.SelectionStart - 1;
                T.Text = T.Text.Remove(CursorIndex, 1);

                //Align Cursor to same index
                T.SelectionStart = CursorIndex;
                T.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248989/A-Currency-Masked-TextBox-from-TextBox-Class

Comment: @Stanley thanks for your answer. I have tried but the format of the currency shown only on labelbox , what if the currency format in the textbox typed?

Comment: You can take a look at "The demo project". Open it and you can see all the code from demo, how to use it.